# JNI Callback to Java on non UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have created a thread in java that does some processing passes the data to legacy C++ using JNI. The C++ code performs some tasks on a separate thread and then returns, at this point I want to callback from JNI into the Java thread rather then the main interface thread. The code seems to build and run without errors, but when CallVoidMethod is called to call back into Java nothing happens, no exceptions or errors, it does seem to invoke the Java code.

I am calling AttachCurrentThread which seems to work and detach at the end, the calls to find the method all seem to succeed. Has anyone got any ideas or have I got the wrong idea?

Comment: Add a log statement at the start of the method you're calling to see if it's being called.  Make sure you call ExceptionCheck in your JNI code to see if something failed on the Java side in CallVoidMethod.  You say "nothing happens" but also "does seem to invoke the Java code", so I'm not really sure what you're seeing or how it's failing.

Comment: If you paste the code, we can suggest you something

Answer (score 2):

There is no silver bullet to fix such problem; you could have any of the miriad little things go wrong. I would suggest to start counterintuitively with some code that does not work. Set the method ID deliberatly wrong; see how the system behaves differently. Set the object reference (or class reference, if it is a static method) to an unexpected object, or a non-existing object; see what happens when the object reference is not globalized... You've got the idea.

Comment: Upvote for the globalized object reference – turns out I need to call `NewGlobalReference()` if I want to keep a reference to an object or class beyond the scope of the current method and thread. See http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references for a good guide on this.